# Find a surjective holomorphic function $f: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb D$ which maximize $|f(z_1)|$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $\Omega$ be a simply connected domain whose boundary has more than one point and $z_0, z_1 \in \Omega$. $\mathscr F=\{f(z)|f:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb D$, $f$ is holomorphic, $f(z_0)=0\}$ is a family of holomorphic functions.

Prove that there exists a surjective function $\phi\in\mathscr F$ s.t. $|\phi(z_1)|=sup|f(z_1)|$ ($f\in\mathscr F)$.

I guess the solution is similar to the proof of Riemann Mapping Theorem, but I have problem when I tried to prove $\phi$ is surjective. 
Assume that $c\in \mathbb D-\phi(\Omega)$, and then I should make a contradiction by proving $\exists\psi\in\mathscr F$ s.t. $|\psi(z_1)| \gt|\phi(z_1)|$. I don't know how to construct $\psi$.

Comment: As stated the claim is wrong. There might be not a single surjective $f$ in the given family. You have to describe the intended families more carefully.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Thanks. I have changed the description.